# Cannot query view but view SQL runs fine in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have designed a view in BigQuery, which references other views and a Google sheet.
From my experience querying google sheets in bigquery adds about 30 seconds onto the time, even if it's a single row, though I can't find any documentation to explain this.
The view consists of 4 CTEs which all reference other views and the google sheet, the SQL in the view takes about 48 seconds to run.

When I save the SQL as a view though, and do a Select * from view, the query has cannot complete, it runs for about 10 minutes and then gives the error 
"Error encountered during execution. Retrying may solve the problem."

I understand that querying views of views is messy, but I can query the view in the editor without problems (just takes about a minute), why is saving it as a view and querying it more problematic?

Here is the query:

```
#standardSQL
with spends as (SELECT y.course,cast(concat(cast(extract (YEAR from date)as string),"-",cast(extract(MONTH from date)as string),"-01")as date)as month,sum(spend) as spend fROM `project.dataset.view1` x
left join (select * from `project.dataset.table1`) as y
on x.account_id = y.id
group by 1,2),

forecasts as (select * from `project.dataset.google_sheet1`),

cds as (select course, sum(spend)/7 as current_daily_spend from (SELECT y.course,
case when date between DATE_SUB(current_date(), interval 7 DAY) and DATE_SUB(current_date(), interval 1 DAY) then sum(spend) else null end AS spend
fROM `project.dataset.view1` x
left join (select * from `project.dataset.table1`) as y
on x.account_id = y.id
group by date,y.course)
group by course),

yesterday as (select course, sum(spend) as yesterday_spend from (SELECT y.course,
case when date = DATE_SUB(current_date(), interval 1 DAY) then sum(spend) else null end AS spend
fROM `project.dataset.view1` x
left join (select * from `project.dataset.table1`) as y
on x.account_id = y.id
group by date,y.course)
group by course)

Select forecasts.*,spends.spend,cds.current_daily_spend,yesterday.yesterday_spend from forecasts
left join spends
on forecasts.month = spends.month and forecasts.course = spends.course
left join cds
on spends.course = cds.course
left join yesterday
on spends.course = yesterday.course
```

Comment: For mysterious errors having a job id helps a lot. Try with the BigQuery issue tracker too

Comment: if you have an issue with your query - it is very important to not to obfuscate your query as you did - for example you have `select * from table1` and `fROM view1` - can you provide exact text of how you reference those  - the reason i ask is because depends how you do it  - it can be a reason for the trouble you see

Comment: The way I reference the tables and views is by the following: "\`project.dataset.table\`", I'm interested to know how this can be done differently and how this would affect the result. Also Felipe, I have the job id, where can I enter it to get more details?

Comment: Hello! I don't know if you still have the issue, but if so, if you have a support package I'd like to ask you to open there a case providing the job ID. Otherwise, please open a private issue in the Public Issue Tracker with the project number and job id directly [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164) and then you can post here the issue number in order to be able to locate you and help you myself.